# Show that a certain number defined via its decimal expansion is not rational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

For each function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ we define the real number, in decimal notation  $A(f)=0.f(0)f(1)f(2)f(3)\ldots $.  Show that, if $f(x) =x^2$, then $A(f)=.0149162536\ldots$ is irrational.

We tried comparing this to the square root of a prime number irrationality proof that we know, but we do not have a function to undo. Similarly we tried to compare this to the proof that proves $\pi$ is irrational, but that did not help either.

Comment: For many such functions $f$ (e.g. $n\mapsto n^k$ with $k$ a fixed positive integer, or $n\mapsto n^\text{th}$prime), the number whose decimal expansion is $A(f)$ is not only irrational, but is [disjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence#Examples); that is, *every possible finite block of digits appears in $A(f)$!*

Answer (score 1):

The decimal $0.01491625\dots$ is neither terminating nor ultimately periodic. One way to see this is that there are arbitrarily long strings of $0$'s in the decimal expansion, because it contains as substrings the squares of $10,100,1000,\dots$.

Any rational number has a terminating decimal expansion, or an ultimately periodic one. So our number is irrational.

Comment: We just wrote out this expansion, and we can see this, 
= 1/100+4/1000+9/10000+16/1000000+......
and we noted that once we get to double digit squares, we have a jump so to say in our decimal expansion, and there is nothing over 10^5. but can we just state this as a proof? it seems trivial

Comment: The fact that, in the number given by the decimal expansion, there are arbitrarily long strings of $0$'s is easy, and a justification is given in the answer. It is then immediate that the given decimal expansion is not ultimately periodic, since if after a while things repeated with period $d$, just wait until you get more than $d$ consecutive $0$'s, and all the digits afterwards would have to be $0$. But they aren't. And now we appeal to a well-known characterization of (positive) rationals as having terminating or ultimately periodic decimal expansions.